# how to mask data fields in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mask

I have a table containing special data and I need to hide those data after I backup them 
for example I have a filed containing phone number like this

0020158578939

I need to make it like this

002015*******

whats is the sql command I must use to do this.
I searched here but didn't find a suitable answer
thank you in advance

Comment: do you mean you want to obscure the data on the server? or obscure the data actually in the backup? or something else

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull I want to obscure the data on the server. thank you :)

Comment: i dont get the intention of it if you want to mask the phones like this (no-rollback) then use just md5() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the column name is `phone`, this SQL statement will do:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(phone, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6)) AS masked_phone
FROM `yourTable`
```

This will only show the first 6 characters and will mask the rest with `*`.

**Update (as per your comment):**

Upon backup, you could generate the following `UPDATE` statement to mask the phone number:

```
UPDATE `yourTable`
SET phone = CONCAT(SUBSTR(phone, 1, 6), REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6))
```

Comment: this is just displaying the phone number masked, what I need is to mask it actualy in the database which means that I need to use UPDATE or any suitable query or command , thank you

Comment: what if I need to mask it from the start like this ****158578939? I tried to modify the query but I failed.

Comment: Try `SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6), SUBSTR(phone, -6)) AS masked_phone FROM yourTable`. Where `6` is the number of characters to include.

Comment: Again with select (^_^)  please use UPDATE :) thank you very much for your help

Comment: `UPDATE yourTable SET phone = CONCAT(REPEAT('*', CHAR_LENGTH(phone) - 6), SUBSTR(phone, -6))`

Comment: you are the best. thank you. you helped me to create GDPR dump.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this phone number again then use :

```
    base64_encode('0020158578939');
```

and when you need it then

```
    base64_decode('your mysql field value of phone');
```

Otherwise use :

```
    md5('0020158578939'); sha1('0020158578939');
```

Comment: no I don't need them again and if I can decrypt them again then any one else can do. but this is a good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to generate the obscured string if the field is a character string:

```
SELECT RPAD(SUBSTR(PhoneNumber, 1, 6), Length(PhoneNumber), '*')
```

See this link how the RPAD function works specificly: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad